# Is there a way that I can compile a Mono project to run natively on linux?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am trying to find a way that I can use mono to build my console application to run natively on Linux (ie: `./ConsoleApp` instead of `mono ConsoleApp.exe`), but have so far been unable to find and solutions that allow me to do this.

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/mkbundle/

Comment: like a native executable, i,e no .Net instructions? or just calling it without "mono"?

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks a lot; that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SushiHangover said in comment:

> mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/mkbundle

That tool was exactly what I needed